# Installing Glass.Mapper

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, glass-mapper

What packages do I need to install in order to setup Glass.Mapper for Sitecore 8.1 with VS2013 and MVC 5.2.3.0 using NuGet? I already have Castle.Windsor.

[image]

I tried Glass.Mapper.Sc on its own, tried BoC.Glass.Mapper.Sc.Mvc-5 on its own, and tried both of them together I always get run time errors when opening the content editor in Sitecore UI:

```
Method not found: '!!0 Glass.Mapper.Context.GetTypeConfiguration(System.Type, Boolean, Boolean)'.
```

Plus which of them do I need for other solution projects?

Update1:
I had to go the sitecore bin folder to remove all Glass.Mapper related DLLs (from previous package installation attempts) and then installed Glass.Mapper.Sc again. Now I can open the Content Editor, however I got an error while publishing:

```
Could not resolve type name: Glass.Mapper.Sc.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.GlassDocumentMapperObjectFactory, Glass.Mapper.Sc.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider (method: Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.CreateFromTypeName(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert)).
```

So I installed `Glass.Mapper.Sc.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider` but then I got another error related to Glass.Mapper's version of Castle.Windsor, so I installed `Glass.Mapper.Sc.CastleWindsor`. 
Now when I click on publish, I get the following:

```
Could not resolve type name: Glass.Mapper.Sc.Events.PublishEnd.GlassCacheClear, Glass.Mapper.Sc (method: Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.CreateFromTypeName(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert)).
```

Comment: RTFM: http://glass.lu/Blog/GlassV4, You just need `Glass.Mapper.Sc` for the official Glass project.

Comment: Thanks, please the above update

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair Can you create a sitecore81 tag then? His use of sitecore81 for me was validated by the fact he probably couldn't create tag for it. Sitecore8 and 81 have numerous differences.

Comment: Just Glass.Mapper.Sc indeed. But you're right, it should be cleaned up. I just removed (or made hidden actually) all BoC.Glass.Mapper < 4.0 versions from NuGet.
BoC.Glass.Mapper.Sc can also be used, it's pretty much in sync with Mike's official release, but has some fixes for CodeFirst and (more importantly) can be used in conjuntion with BoC.Glass.Mapper.Sc.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider -> Allows mapping from the lucene-index, being much faster then mapping on a dbitem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are using on same environment like you GlassMapper 4.0.5.54.
You don't need to use Boc.Glass.Mapper.Sc.Mvc

[image]

On packages.config we have

```
<package id="Glass.Mapper.Sc" version="4.0.5.54" targetFramework="net45" />
```

To install a specif version you can use command line:

Install-Package CGlass.Mapper.Sc -Version 4.0.5.54

Comment: Thanks, I already tried it. However this time i made sure no other DLLs were still there from previous attempts. So it works now. I can open the Content Editor. However see the original question.

Comment: Can you try on a clean solution, you can do it like in this video except Mvc part https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pL4bBi90-ZM

Comment: Before I tried on a clean instance. I rechecked all Glass.Mapper DLLs and files to return my instance into a Glass.Mapper-free one. It seems there were config files also from previous package installation attempts. I deleted everything and then installed again. Now it works. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It's worth going to the [glass website and viewing tutorials](http://www.glass.lu/Mapper/Sc/Tutorials/Tutorial1). To quote the linked page:

> Before install Glass.Mapper.Sc you need to reference the following
>   assemblies in your project:
>
> - Sitecore.Kernel.dll
> - System.Web.Mvc.dll
>
> Both these files can be found in the bin folder of your Sitecore solution. These assemblies are used
>   to determine which version of the Glass.Mapper assemblies should be
>   referenced.
>
> Once you have added the references above to your project you can
>   download Glass.Mapper.Sc from Nuget. Open the Nuget Package Manager
>   and search for Glass.Mapper.Sc:
>
> Glass.Mapper.Sc V4 Nuget Package in Package Manager
>
> The Nuget package will add references to the Glass.Mapper.dll,
>   Glass.Mapper.Sc.dll, Glass.Mapper.Sc.Mvc.dll and Castle.Core.dll:
>
> V4 Reference add to Project
>
> The Nuget package also install some additional CS files and config
>   files:
>
> Glass.Mapper.Sc V4 Files added to Project
>
> You are now ready to start working with Glass.Mapper. Tutorial 2 will
>   show you how to create your first model.

Comment: Thank you. I did read this, however, other pages like the following instruct to install MVC-5: http://glass.lu/Mapper/Sc/Tutorials/Tutorial12 and http://glass.lu/Blog/GlassAndSitecoreMvc

Comment: I can see how that would confuse you :p. :) If you follow from step one it should of got you up and running no problem.

Comment: Tutorial links taken down in favor of paid training. Use archived links from 2017 Dec or earlier: https://web.archive.org/web/20171222143913/http://www.glass.lu/Mapper/Sc/Tutorials/Tutorial1

Answer (score 0):

I Resolved it by commenting out

```
<handler type="Glass.Mapper.Sc.Events.PublishEnd.GlassCacheClear, Glass.Mapper.Sc" method="ClearCache">;
```

in `lass.Mapper.Sc.config` file.

Good luck.